# Postfix Not receiving emails 550 authentication required

Tags: email

Postfix | Roundcube | Plesk panel Outgoing emails go away (although they end up in spam), but incoming emails do not arrive. Writes: Message not delivered. Failed to deliver message to recipient admin@domen.net See the technical details below. Remote server response: 550 Authentication required

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_tls_security_level = may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = vm45901.cs.easyname.systems
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost.localdomain, localhost.cs.easyname.systems, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
transport_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/certs
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtp_use_tls = no
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
# smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject
authorized_flush_users = 
authorized_mailq_users = 
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
plesk_virtual_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
message_size_limit = 10240000
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
smtputf8_enable = no
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /opt/psa/etc/dhparams2048.pem
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
smtpd_tls_protocols = TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
tls_medium_cipherlist = EECDH+AESGCM+AES128:EECDH+AESGCM+AES256:EECDH+CHACHA20:EDH+AESGCM+AES128:EDH+AESGCM+AES256:EDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+SHA256+AES128:EECDH+SHA384+AES256:EDH+SHA256+AES128:EDH+SHA256+AES256:EECDH+SHA1+AES128:EECDH+SHA1+AES256:EDH+SHA1+AES128:EDH+SHA1+AES256:EECDH+HIGH:EDH+HIGH:AESGCM+AES128:AESGCM+AES256:CHACHA20:SHA256+AES128:SHA256+AES256:SHA1+AES128:SHA1+AES256:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK:!KRB5:!aECDH:!kDH
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
recipient_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:12346
recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient,header_recipient
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139597/discussion-on-question-by-sergei-sokov-postfix-not-receiving-emails-550-authenti).

Comment: reload конечно каждый раз делаю. Я тебе там в чате написал. А тут ничего нет.